# How do I understand the passitive verb "killed" without a "be"?

Tags: word-usage

[Khashoggi case tests Washington’s attitude to human rights](http://www.globaltimes.cn/content/1123266.shtml)

> As the US and Turkey are strengthening communication with Saudi
>   Arabia, the tension over missing journalist Jamal Khashoggi,
>   reportedly **killed** inside the consulate, is expected to abate.

I think there should be a "was" before "killed". I searhed "killed". There are many news titles just with "killed", such as,

> 9 killed and 21 injured ...

I think the titles use a such short term due to the lack of space (for a full sentence.)

Comment: If you had said "the tension [...], reportedly *was* killed inside the consulate" then you would literally be saying that the *tension* was killed.

Comment: "There are many news titles just with "killed", such as, '9 killed' ..." - This is called *ellipsis*. Yes, it is commonly done in headlines. See also: [Struggling to understand headlines that use ellipsis](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101809/struggling-to-understand-headlines-that-use-ellipsis). A complete statement would be "scores are dead" but in a headline you often elide this verb, yielding occasionally odd looking word combinations like "scores dead".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you should read [this grammar rule](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/past_participles.htm) about the Past Participle.

> Past participles can often be found in participle phrases. A participle phrase acts like an adjective. In the examples below, the participle phrases are shaded and the past participles are in bold:
>
> *The boy **taken** to hospital has recovered*. (The participle phrase
>   taken to hospital describes the boy.)

In your example, the past participle phrase "*reportedly killed inside the consulate*" modifies "*missing journalist Jamal Khashoggi*".

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a reference handy, but my feeling here is that "killed inside the consulate" is a state, not a past tense verb. The news title you cite certainly fits that: killed and injured being states of being. ("9 killed, 21 injured, 800 displaced...")

If you want to put "was" before "killed", then you would have to put "who" before "was", again turning the whole thing into a state. Jamal Khashoggi, who was killed inside the consulate, ...